# Eigenvalue Localization

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, permutations

> Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be a normal matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$. Show there exists a permutation $\pi$ of $1, \dots n$ so that $$ \sum_{i=1}^n\left|a_{i i}-\lambda_{\pi(i)}\right|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j \neq i}\left|a_{i j}\right|^2.$$

---

I tried to use Gershgorin’s Theorem, which says for an eigenvalue $\lambda$, ${|a_{ii}-\lambda|} \leqslant \sum_{j=1, i \neq j}^n {|a_{ij}|}$. However, if we take square on both sides, we cannot obtain the RHS of the inequality. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A = U \Lambda U^H$ be an eigendecomposition for $A$. The claim is that there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that

$$ \left \Vert \mathrm{diag(A)} - P\mathrm \Lambda P^T \right \Vert_F^2 \leq  \left \Vert A - \mathrm{diag}(A) \right \Vert_F^2,$$

where $\mathrm{diag}:\mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ maps all off-diagonal elements to $0$ and keeps the diagonal elements the same.

By unitary invariance of Frobenius norm, the claim is equivalent to
$$
\exists \mathrm{~permutation~} P : \left \Vert  \Lambda   - P^T \mathrm{diag(A)} P\right \Vert_F^2  \leq \left \Vert A - \mathrm{diag}(A) \right \Vert_F^2.
$$

The result follows from the [Hoffman-Wielandt Inequality](https://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2011/12/03/the-hoffman-wielandt-inequality/).